# Adobe InDesign GREP over multiple lines and paragraphs

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I try to create an InDesign syntax highlighting script for Lua code.

Something very simple and basic. I decided to go with [this native approach](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6996/indesign-and-syntax-highlighting/6998#6998). I've got strings and numbers and single-line comments already covered. But I'm having trouble with multi-line strings and multi-line comments.

Multiline text begins with `[[` and ends with `]]` (possibly spanning over multiple paragraphs).
Multiline comments are same, but beginn with `--[[` and end with (at least) `]]`. You find some examples down below.

**The question is, how can I apply a GREP search onto multiple paragraphs in InDesign?** I've already tried all kinds of variants with lookbehind and lookahead and also the `(?s)` modifier which seems to work only on until the next line break.

```lua
local text = [[   Lua

multi
line
string]]

--[[
    multiline comment
--]]

--[[ alternative
multi-

    line
comment
]]
```

[image]

Comment: You are not using a script, you are using a native function of InDesign and so this is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. [graphicdesign.se] may be a better place to ask. *However:* GREP Styles cannot span multiple paragraphs; that's why your approach is doomed to fail. If you use a script instead, it may be possible.

Comment: As @usr2564301 has already pointed out _"GREP Styles cannot span multiple paragraphs"_. You may want to consider using "Find/Change" instead. i.e. use this pattern; [`--\[\[[\S\s]*?\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/p2m3t6/1/) in the _"Find What"_ field to find multi-line comments, and similarly this pattern; [`(?<!--)\[\[[\S\s]*?\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/2pLpok/1/) to find multi-line text. Then in the _"Change Format"_ choose the appropriate _Character Style_.